# Причина закрытия "не по теме"

Tags: предложение, локализация, причины-закрытия

Текст причины закрытия [вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/135140/%d0%93%d0%b4%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-ttf-%d1%88%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%84%d1%82%d1%8b) "не по теме" в текущем варианте звучит, имхо, несколько не по-русски:

> закрыт по причине того, что не по теме участниками ...

Предлагаю найти более качественные варианты.

Comment: Повторю то, что уже писал в чате: "не по теме" в русском языке имеет другой оттенок смысла. Вроде как "неуместно, невовремя".

Comment: Таки что в итоге? -_+

Answer (score 4):

Считаю, что значительно лучше существующего будет выглядеть такой вариант:

> закрыт по причине того, что не соответствует тематике сайта участниками ...

Вероятно ещё надо добавить запятую перед "участниками". По идее это не должно противоречить [общей фразе закрытия](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/51941586?key=e524f84c8a121616644f769dbc18412a) из transifex:

> **закрыт** по причине того, что $closeReason$ участниками $userCommas$ $onDate$

Comment: А зачем кавычки? Вопрос же в буквальном смысле не соответствует, а не в переносном.

Comment: @NickVolynkin хм-м ... наверное я думал о варианте `закрыт по причине «не соответствует тематике сайта» участниками ...` когда писал ответ. Сейчас уберу тогда кавычки, пока ещё не началось голосование.

Comment: @NickVolynkin ещё почему-то очень хочется запятую перед `участниками`.

Comment: Ага, верно. Не факт, что движок позволит.

Comment: @NickVolynkin добавил инфу про запятую. И [вопрос](http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/427654/%d0%9d%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8) на сайт русского языка.

Comment: Где вторая запятая-то?

Comment: @Qwertiy в тексте

Comment: @alexolut, после `$closeReason$` нужна запятая.

Answer (score 1):

[Вариант](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/427654/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8#comment431009_427655) от участника сообщества "Русский язык":

> закрыт, так как не соответствует тематике сайта, - участниками ...

Общая форма для transifex будет такой:

> закрыт, так как $closeReason$, - участниками $userCommas$ $onDate$

Answer (score 1):

Мой вариант перевода:

> Объявлен требующим правки как не соответствующий тематике сайта X часов назад участниками A, B, C. Участники указывали следующую причину: ...

Здесь самое важное (факт и причина закрытия) идет непрерывным текстом в начале, а второстепенные детали (кто и когда закрыл) в конце. (Изначально было опубликовано в виде [вопроса](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7598/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD))

Comment: "Требующий правки" и "закрыт" это разные состояния вопроса. Я отменил голос за дубликат. И получается, что текущий ответ тут не к месту.