# Текст в плашке "Вопрос не по теме" не согласован

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, локализация

Меня давно смущает текст в желтой плашке вопросах, закрытых как оффтоп, например:

[image: Скриншот сообщения об оффтопе]

"так как не по теме" звучит как–то не согласованно с началом предложения.

Предлагаю вариант:

> Объявлен X часов назад требующим правки участниками A, B, C как не соответствующий тематике сайта. Те, кто голосовал за его закрытие, указывали следующую причину:

Или так (но это канцеляритом отдает):

> Объявлен X часов назад требующим правки участниками A, B, C по причине несоответствия тематике сайта. Те, кто голосовал за его закрытие, указывали следующую причину:

А вообще, лучше всего немного порядок слов поменять, так как "требующим правки" и "как не соответствующий" связаны по смыслу, но разделены другими словами. И второе предложение тоже можно упростить:

> Объявлен требующим правки как не соответствующий тематике сайта X часов назад участниками A, B, C. Участники указывали следующую причину:

Здесь самое важное (факт и причина закрытия) идет непрерывным текстом в начале, а второстепенные детали (кто и когда закрыл) в конце.

**UPD**

Я посмотрел вопрос, дубликатом которого предлагается считать мой. Предложенные там варианты мне нравятся меньше, чем мой последний вариант, но, как я понял из комментариев тут и там, есть ограничения движка, которые не удастся обойти (по крайней мере, малой кровью). Поэтому хотелось бы знать эти ограничения, чтобы иметь общее представление, какова должна быть структура текста. Ну и просто на будущее, чтобы знать, что имеет смысл предлагать, а что нет. Возможно, стоит зайти на общую мету и предложить там проапгрейдить движок?

Можно ли для каждой причины закрытия написать свой собственный текст? Если нет, то это тоже осложняет дело, так как предложенный мной вариант для оффтопа может плохо сочетаться с текстами других причин (я не проверял), и тогда их тоже придется править, и т. д.

Comment: @Nicolas уточните цель правки плиз? Мне что старый вариант *режет глаз*, что новый, кажется *корявым*. В сообщении о правке никакого информативного послания нет, кроме *"из текста удалено 18 символов; изменён заголовок"*

Comment: @Kromster Отписался автору ответа [тут](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81257/room-for-nicolas-chabanovsky-and-dmitry).

Comment: Ваши предложения меняют структуру текста. Т.е. вы предлагаете заменить три предложения на два, верно?

Comment: Да, что-то вроде того. Мне самому больше всего нравится последний вариант, но там надо все переделывать. А в первом варианте просто небольшой кусок в конце заменить.

Comment: Вероятно, с этим могут возникнуть технические проблемы.. Мы не можем, скажем, перевести предложение пустой строкой - оно появится на английском. Но ладно, подождём переводчиков (а то я что-то оригиналы найти не могу)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Причина закрытия "не по теме"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3952/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5)

Comment: @Dmitry, просто перенесите ваши предложения в ответ под тем вопросом.

Comment: @vp_arth Перенес

Comment: @alexolut ну какой тут дубликат-то? Тот вопрос уже десять раз устарел, судя по тому что я вижу.

Comment: @alexolut текущий перевод не указан там ни в вопросе, ни в ответах...

Comment: @PavelMayorov не дубликат. Но не потому, что устарел. Просто описывает вопрос на разных стадиях: "требует правки" предшествует "закрытию". Но помимо меня ещё трое не обратили на это внимание. Свой голос отозвал.

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я вижу, в текущей реализации плашек такого варианта текста уже не встречается. Есть, например, такой вариант:

> [image: Не по теме]

Ранее подобные вопросы (закрытые в течение последних 5 дней) как раз помечались как "требует правки". Теперь они просто "закрыты".

Кстати, нашлось предложение пятилетней давности: [Заменить «Требует правки» на «Закрыт»](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/739/176217) Оно, получается, тоже уже теряет свою актуальность.