# Что есть отзыв, а что отзывом не является?

Tags: обсуждение, модерация

Stack Overflow — это не только библиотека готовых решений, но и сообщество увлеченных энтузиастов программирования. Мы все разные, у каждого есть свое видение того, как должен выглядеть сайт. Чтобы поделиться идеями, дать отзыв и предложить инициативы мы используем [Мету](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/), иногда, [общий чат сообщества](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--).

Как мне кажется (судя по прошлому году), есть участники, которые неверно понимают, зачем нужны отзывы на Stack Overflow, что есть отзыв, а что отзывом не является, что есть дружеское напоминание о незавершенной инициативе, а что — грубое или даже агрессивное поведение, что есть обсуждение критических проблем, а когда оскорбление пытаются подать под «собственным мнением» высказанным «на благо сообщества» .

Давайте попробуем разобраться в этих вопросах вместе!

Пожалуйста, расскажите:

- Какие, на ваш взгляд, отзывы уместны на сайте, а какие лучше не публиковать, а увидев удалять?
- Что по вашему есть критика? В каком виде она допустима на сайте?

И, что самое главное, почему вы так считаете?

Мы все несовершенны. То, как мы помогаем друг другу становиться лучше может объединять, а может отталкивать. Пожалуйста, не оставайтесь в стороне. Расскажите, какие подходы к отзывам, которые будут объединять, видите вы.

Comment: Попробую угадать TL;DR, как увидел его в этом вопросе я: *"Какие вопросы на Мете и сообщения в чате вам не понравились и почему?"* Верно?

Comment: @Kromster Не совсем. Это скорее о подходе, чем о конкретных сообщениях. Например, нам можно всем сунуть руки в брюки и ходить говорить, что на русском языке база знаний не возможна и тд. А можно самоорганизоваться и двигаться вперед.

Comment: Данное сообщество ещё не готово к каким-либо глобальным переменам, ИМХО (из наблюдений за последний год), база знаний по-тихоньку накапливается, критическая масса постоянных учасников растет, всё идет своим чередом. А работать ещё упорнее я не могу физически, я и так в сообщество вкладываю по 2 часа минимум каждый день, а есть ещё жизнь, работа и т.д. К чему эти все последние перепалки? Если честно, эти постоянные перепалки то на Мета, то в чате, только отталкивают от сообщества.

Comment: Я заполнял опрос (вроде он получасовой), на AskUbuntu в этом году, ну он впринципе стандартый для всего SO, если честно SO перегнуло палку с некоторыми вопросами, по поводу всяких там ориентаций, данных о семье и т. д.(зачем это вообще, как это отностится к программированию или системному администрированию?) и ещё ряду вопросов, на которые большинство, я так понимаю, вообще не отвечало. Надеюсь когда на ruSO будет такой опрос, вопросы изменят.

Comment: @L.F.C. Вроде когда был опрос на enSO, если не ошибаюсь, был вопросы о доходе.... интересно это тоже как-то влияет на развитие сообщества)

Comment: @AlexanderSemikashev это как раз *и ещё ряду вопросов* , был и такой. Ответ на развитие сообщества никак не влияет. Я очень надеюсь, ОЧЕНЬ, что данные не сольют куда-то (хоть там и написано *честно-честно, никому*), а то обилие не относящихся к теме вопросов, честно говоря, смущает

Comment: Я очень позитивно настроен в отношении данного сообщества и в отношении сети StackExchange в целом. Прилагаю усилия, какие могу, чтоб сообщество развивалось и радовало участников. Если я ошибаюсь и меня критикуют, я принимаю критику, какая-бы она не была, так как понимаю, что ошибаться может даже самый опытный воин, хоть я таким себя не считаю.

Comment: Но самое главное из всех ответов и поста в целом, я вижу одну общую нить. Тут вопрос не в критике как таковой, а в попытках оскорбить, тех или иных людей. И если честно, когда очень стараешься сделать что-то полезное и даже пусть не всегда как надо, а в ответ на свой энтузиазм получаешь какое-то оскорбление, боевой дух падает до минимума. Давайте просто соблюдать правила и уважать друг друга, не за мнения, а просто за то, что мы живые люди.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

На мой взгляд, крайне важно поддерживать на Мете и в чате (как, конечно же, и на основном сайте) атмосферу безопасности, в которой хочется делиться мыслями, в которой понимаешь, что твои идеи услышаны.  Отзывы мы не только даем, но и принимаем. Если вы даете отзыв, к примеру, модератору, в одном виде, но не приемлете такого же подхода к себе, нам стоит поменять подход к способу донесения мыслей друг до друга. Правила должны быть одинаковые для всех.

#### Какие отзывы допустимы?

Самое важное в отзыве — чтобы его принял человек, кому он адресован. Это возможно только если отзыв высказывается *с уважением*, не содержит оскорблений или нападков на личность и включает обоснования *почему* что–то стоит менять, *как* менять и *кому* следует это делать. [Отзыв должен быть о проблемном поведении, а не о личности человека](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4790/6). Можно говорить, что отзыв должен основываться на суждении, а не мнении.

#### Отзывы основанные на личном мнении

Иметь свое мнение — очень здорово. Многообразие мыслей крайне необходимо! Без авангарда взглядов мы не сможем добиться много. Самое важное — уметь донести свое мнение до слушателя не переходя черту уважения. Попробую пояснить на комическом примере.

Представьте, что у вас есть очень талантливый, умный, приятный коллега, который приходит на работу в пиджаке, а вы так не любите людей в пиджаке. Вы подходите к нему и говорите, что носить пиджак не модно. Он жмет вам руку и продолжает ходить в пиджаке. На этом, на мой взгляд, стоит остановиться в распространении своего мнения. Проблема возникает тогда, когда люди продолжают навязывать свое мнение окружающим, что хуже, кто–то даже начинает высмеивать «парня в пиджаке», если тот не прислушивается к их мнению. Всем, в том числе окружающим, от такого «мнения» становится неуютно.

Делиться своим мнением очень важно, но еще важнее делать это с уважением, не прибегая к навязыванию. То, что кто–то делает не так, как хотелось бы вам, не означает, что «иной подход» неверен.

#### Нетерпимость и негативное мнение о других

Каждый имеет право на свое мнение, как и на общечеловеческое уважение, отношение к себе как к личности. Оскорбление не становится менее оскорбительным если подается под соусом «собственного мнения», даже если вы действительно думаете так.

На мой взгляд, подобному не место на нашем сайте ни в каком виде. Нетерпимость и агрессия противоречат [Нормам поведения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/conduct) на сайте.

#### Негатив, агрессия и высмеивание

Весь наш сайт — это инициатива неравнодушных людей. База знаний пополняется волонтерами, для которых важно получение удовольствия от использования сайта и конечная миссия проекта. Когда мы видим пессимизм, в том числе ничем не подкрепленный, поданный как «мнение», общее желание помогать коллегам на сайте падает. Опять же шуточный пример.

Представьте, что вас попросили написать стихи в местную газету. Вы, воодушевленный возможностью проявить себя, тратите несколько вечеров. Когда стихи практически завершены, к вам заходит знакомый и непонятно почему начинает сыпать колкости в адрес газеты, ее редактора, а потом высказывает «личное мнение» о вашем творчестве, о успехе предприятия, да и вообще «все бы было хорошо, если бы не было так плохо». Все, желание что–либо публиковать пропало. Как и участвовать в подобном в будущем.

На мой взгляд, допускать подобное нельзя. Агрессия да и вообще негатив распространяется как вирус, снижает активность в сообществе, разрушает вовлечение. Драмы, какими бы надуманными они не были, деморализуют участников. Негатив приводит к стагнации.

Пожалуйста, не публикуйте подобного на сайтах сети Stack Exchange.

#### Что есть критика, а что ей не является

> [Критика](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)  — это анализ, оценка и суждение о явлениях какой-либо области человеческой деятельности.

Как видно из определения, личное мнение критикой не является, как и оскорбления. Критика подразумевает суждение и анализ, то есть должна быть подкреплена доводами. Язвить != критиковать. Критиковать необходимо уметь.

#### Говорить о проблемах надо!

Скрывать проблемы бессмысленно и глупо, ровно также как и навязывать силой свое видение решения проблем. Говорить о проблемах можно и нужно открыто, с уважением. Наш девиз — «Не ошибается лишь тот, кто ничего не делает».

Пожалуйста, если вы видите недочет в модерации, программном обеспечении платформы или чувствуете, что сайт можно улучшить какой–либо инициативой, обязательно расскажите об этом сообществу.

Comment: Поставил + всем отвечающим. По поводу критики и агрессии, можно упомянуть, что критика имеет две стороны, она бывает конструктивной и деструктивной. Вторая - очень плохой вариант.

Comment: @L.F.C. основной вопрос в том, кто судить будет? Сейчас в случае с некоторым участниками выборочно администратор в обход модераторов решения принимает.

Comment: Почему из приведенного определения критики следует, что личное мнение критикой не является?

Comment: @yolosora Все просто. Мнение, как минимум, что мы видели в последний год, высказывается на правах «я так считаю», а не рассуждений вида «я думаю так, потому что», то есть в нем нет анализа, а больше эмоций. Это уже что–то другое, но не критика. Подскажите, что вы думаете об этом?

Comment: «Он жмет вам руку и продолжает ходить в пиджаке.» — я так понимаю, это как раз подпадает под определение пассивной агрессии.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky дело в том, что анализ, оценка и суждения могут строиться не только на сухих верных для всех утверждениях, но и на ощущениях (самые банальные примеры - критика искусства или продуктов питания), а суждения построенные на ощущениях - личное мнение

Comment: @yolosora Мы же говорим о правилах сообщества. Без суждений и анализа это скатится «я считаю так, мое мнение важнее». Кроме того, произведения искусства критикуют тоже по делу с анализом, на ощущениях только казуальные обыватели галерей судят =)

Comment: Николай, мне вот еще интересно, вам эти темы сверху спускают или это всё личная инициатива?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky решительно не соглашусь, в критике искусства есть элементы сухого теоретического анализа, но основная масса тезисов все таки на разной глубины ощущениях. К чему я собственно клоню в наших реалиях - помимо сухих фактов со статистикой и "пруфами" - имеет место такая вещь как субъективных дискомфорт, базирующийся на разных ощущениях. И если уж Вы как менеджер пришедший из технарской среды так любите абстрагироваться от мира ощущений и слушаете только факты, то ощущения тоже можно перевести в статистику - анонимным опросником вида "Приятно ли вам быть частью сообщества"

Comment: Что-то мне этот ответ напоминает анекдот: "За что я любил покойного, так это за острую критику снизу, сказал медведь, садясь на ежа"...

Comment: Если бы текст состоял только лишь из фразы "я во всём согласен с правилами дружелюбного поведения" и дана ссылка на правила -- это было бы пост под которым многие (и я тоже) поставили бы плюс. Но в текущем виде у меня (возможно и у других) этот пост вызывает отторжение, потому что это копипаста из CoC и я вижу в этом шаблонное промывание на тему "будьте дружелюбными". Оно уже становится слишком навязчивым. Право, один раз привести в справке -- вполне достаточно.

Answer (score 8):

> Какие, на ваш взгляд, отзывы уместны на сайте, а какие лучше не публиковать, а увидев удалять?

Удалять оскорбления и ненормативную лексику. Все остальное - можно. (Примечание: лично я не имею ничего против ненормативной лексики, если она идет не сама по себе, а для придания большей эмоциональности тексту. Но раз нельзя - то не буду.)

> В чем вы видите пассивную агрессию?

Не вижу никакой пассивной агрессии.

> Что по вашему есть критика?

Я предпочитаю использовать наиболее употребимые значения слов. Если я задумываюсь на тему "что такое X", первым делом иду и смотрю какой-нибудь толковый словарь:

> Кри́тика — это анализ, оценка и суждение о явлениях какой-либо области человеческой деятельности. (Википедия со ссылкой на Большой энциклопедический словарь.)

Если кто-то использует это слово в другом значении, но при этом не уточняет, в каком именно - ССЗБ.

> В каком виде она допустима на сайте?

См. п. 1.

И пара слов о себе.
После того, как я начал активно отвечать на вопросы на ruSO, я также начал время от времени заглядывать на мету. Здесь периодически возникают вопросы, подобные этому, - "как нам обустроить ruSO". После прочтения вопросов, ответов и комментариев у меня сложилось впечатление, что наибольшее количество конфликтов между участниками, которые пишут на мете, возникают именно в таких вопросах. Последней каплей для меня лично стал мой [вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7598/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD) про "корявый текст". Я написал, что "текст  корявый", и вы раздули из этого какую-то прямо феерию, что я и переводчиков оскорбил, и не ценю, и они уже и аппетит потеряли, и мотивацию, и больше ничего никогда не переведут. Сколько лет живу, все вокруг употребляют это выражение, и ничего страшного ни с кем не случилось. И вообще, словом "корявый" я охарактеризовал текст, а не автора текста, с чего это ему быть оскрблением? (Это риторический вопрос, отвечать на него не нужно, ответ я уже знаю.)
В общем, я с тех пор на мету если и захожу, то только чтобы быстренько спросить и сразу уйти. Сегодня зашел, чтобы про баг с переводом написать, ну и увидел очередной вопрос про выяснение отношений. Последний раз что-нибудь напишу тут и всё. Я себя не считаю частью сообщества и считать не хочу. Буду тихонечко сидеть себе и отвечать на вопросы по ораклу по мере сил и желания.

Comment: Пост очень по делу, плюсанул. Не очередное шаблонное промывание "будьте дружелюбными", а прямо говорится, что легко увидеть оскорбления и мат, но различить "дружеское напоминание о незавершенной инициативе и пассивную агрессию" во много раз сложнее, если вообще возможно. А то возможно, что пассивная агрессия -- она лишь в глазах смотрящего. Единственное, что отсидеться в QA не получится: там тоже люди и с ними тоже приходится так или иначе взаимодействовать.

Comment: "Последний раз что-нибудь напишу тут и всё. Я себя не считаю частью сообщества и считать не хочу"   (｡•́︿•̀｡)

Comment: Понятное дело, что сам факт таких вандальных правок неприятен, но вы, к слову, всегда можете откатить такие правки ведь.

Comment: Вам скорее всего не удастся отсидеться тихонечко в углу. Когда-нибудь какая-то из многочисленных здешних проблем настигнет и вас.

Comment: @VladD Так уже удается! Полгода назад перестал читать дискуссии о нормах поведения и прочую такую дребедень - и всё сразу стало отлично. А какие тут еще проблемы? Всякий неадекват, ругань, мат и прочее вполне оперативно чистится, тут у меня никаких претензий нет, я более чем доволен. А просто хронические идиоты мне не встречаются - их к ораклу не подпускают обычно :)))

Comment: Чистится не только мат и ругань, чистится вообще всё.

Answer (score 6):

> Расскажите, какие подходы к отзывам, которые будут объединять, видите
>   вы.

Прежде всего, честность и терпимость (желательно со всех сторон).

И уж, конечно, никаких удалений  отзывов и банов за высказывания (по крайней мере за посты без обсценной лексики).

Естественно, конструктивные предложения в критических отзывах крайне желательны.

Comment: Спасибо! Соглашусь и уточню «*никаких удалений отзывов и банов за высказывания (по крайней мере за посты без обсценной лексики).*». Подскажите, пожалуйста, что если (1) ответ об одном, а отзыв совершенно о другом (аналог — вопрос о C++, а ответ про несправедливость политических решений в нашей стране); (2) обсценной лексики нет, но ответ явно унижает, высмеивает других людей. Будем ли оставлять такие ответы? Нужны ли они? На мой взгляд, даже если ответ (отзыв) затрагивает важную тему, но он не уместен в контексте сайта или дискуссии, его следует либо удалить, либо опубликовать отдельно.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, 1) да, удалить, естественно, 5-ю (или сколько там сейчас надо) участниками с возможностью восстановления другими (т.е. обычная процедура). В свете конкретного ответа AK тут, imho он по теме, как обычно кому не нравится -- минусуют; 2) Да, оставляем. Опять же кого обидели -- те минусуют, жмут удалить, пишут комментарии и т.п. Вообще, законодательная защита администрацией "прав верующих" -- дорога в ад

Comment: Отслеживание соблюдения правил — естественная и неотъемлемая часть по защиты общего цветущего сада от его разрушения. [Наша история стара как этот мир](https://lesswrong.ru/w/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC_%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82_%D1%83%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%8B). Отзывы — это отлично, иметь свое мнение — очень важно, я об этом писал, но выдавать за общеизвестные истины какую–то свою надуманную реальность, причем совершенно в другом вопросе, это не отзыв, а промывка мозгов какая-то.

Comment: Лично для меня это все выглядит так, что когда я прихожу в магазин и интересуюсь ценой шорт, мне начинают рассказывать, что в таких же ходит какая–то там знаменитость и я  буду молодцом если куплю и тд,и тп, вместо конкретного ответа. Это называется «вкручивать», «навязывать». Не знаю как думают остальные, но на мой взгляд, такой подход ужасен и контр продуктивен.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, в любом конкретном случае надо действовать по обстоятельствам, в соответствии со здравым смыслом, держа в уме все возможные последствия.

Answer (score 5):

> Что есть отзыв, а что отзывом не является?

В первую очередь я бы хотел обратить внимание на то, что нигде на stackoverflow и на мете ранее не было дано чёткого определения термину "отзыв". И я хочу заострить внимание на том, что мельком и мимоходом вводится новое понятие:

> Чтобы поделиться идеями, дать отзыв и предложить инициативы мы
>   используем Мету, иногда, общий чат сообщества.

И я считаю подобный ввод мимоходом новых терминов, *как будто они существовали всегда* крайне опасной вещью, ведь по сути задаётся очень важный вопрос: "скажите, а как вы считаете, какие отзывы нужно удалять".

Что это означает в практическом плане? Что модераторский состав будет обязан принять эту тему на мете к исполнению: так прогосовали участники — так и необходимо будет поступать при рассмотрении подходящих кейсов. Фактически — любых кейсов на мете. Да-да, любых — потому что без чёткого определения термина "отзыв" можно будет считать любой текст на мете "отзывом". Смотрите за руками: чтобы дать отзыв — мы используем мету, значит наоборот тоже верно: текст дан на мете — значит это отзыв, логично же?

*Важно. Любая чёткая и недвусмысленная формулировка правила намного лучше, чем допускающая неоднозначное трактование на основе личного мнения.*

Ещё раз хочу заострить внимание на том, что ни в этой теме нет чёткого объяснения, что такое отзыв, ни в темах ранее такого не было. Должны ли мы считать, что администрация оставляет самим участникам возможность высказаться, что является отзывом и после этого озвучит в каком-то документе точный термин? Должны ли мы считать, что администрация считает термин настолько понятным, что он не нуждается в чёткой фиксации и определении и нужно сразу переходить к обсуждению "какой отзыв нужно сразу удалять"?

Второй вариант мне кажется особенно опасным, поэтому я позволю задать несколько простых вопросов:

1. Является ли любой вопрос на мете отзывом?
2. Является ли любой ответ на мете отзывом?
3. Является ли любой комментарий на мете отзывом?

Для меня ответ очевиден — все три раза это "нет". Поэтому давайте определимся: прежде чем говорить об удалении с меты текстов - нужно сначала показать, что этот текст является а) отзывом б) отзывом, подлежащим удалению.

После этого я хотел бы обратить внимание, а *кто* будет решать, чем является текст — отзывом или нет. В теме определения нет, ранее определения не было. Значит — в каждом конкретном случае нужно определяться по месту? Будут ли это делать модераторы? Будут ли это делать участники через механизм флагов (новая причина в списке тревог?)

Следующий вопрос. Каким-то образом отзыв был удалён. Каким образом участник, оставивший вопрос, ответ и особенно комментарий под вопросом/ответом узнает о том, что его текст был удалён? Я не знаю подобного механизма, кроме того мне непонятно, каким образом восстанавливать текст из комментария, особенно если удалить спустя месяц после написания.

Тут сразу несколько проблем: во-первых, удаление может быть оспорено (ведь может же? или о удалении отзыва нельзя быть уведомленным и его нельзя оспорить?); во-вторых просмотр удалённых комментариев возможен только с уровнем "модератор" и выше. Хотим ли мы возложить подобную нагрузку на модераторов? Есть ли какие-то готовые механизмы в движке, которые могут автоматизировать данные операции по уведомлению о удалении, подаче апелляции и восстановлению текста (в исходном или отредактированном виде)

Я не помню, чтобы подобные вопросы хотя бы в каком-то аспекте подымались на мете ранее. Либо были введены соответствующие термины в разделах справки. Вероятно, стоит поставить вопрос о том, а нужно ли вообще продолжать сбор мнений участников меты на предмет "а какие отзывы лучше не публиковать, а увидев — удалять". То есть: закрываем вопрос. После этого проясняем термины в другой теме собираем мнения участников "что есть отзыв" либо получаем уведомление администрации "отзывом считается то-то и то-то". И только после этого открываем вопрос, чтобы вернуться к теме "какие отзывы постить нельзя, увидев — можно удалять (кому и как удалять)"

> Как мне кажется (судя по прошлому году), есть участники, которые
>   неверно понимают, зачем нужны отзывы на Stack Overflow, что есть
>   отзыв, а что отзывом не является, что есть дружеское напоминание о
>   незавершенной инициативе, а что — грубое или даже агрессивное
>   поведение, что есть обсуждение критических проблем, а когда
>   оскорбление пытаются подать под «собственным мнением» высказанным «на
>   благо сообщества» .

С учётом того, что неявно постулируется "все мы умные люди и знаем, что есть отзыв" (я показал выше, что это неверно - и есть множество вопросов к самому термину отзыв. Также вы можете просто посчитать меня участником, который не понимает в прошлом году, что есть отзыв и не понимает и сейчас) я продолжу обсуждение вопроса в том сыром виде, в котором он был создан. (Если вы видите этот мой текст удалённым — то имейте ввиду, это уже вторая редакция этого сырого вопроса, которая привела мой текст к удалению. Прошлый ответ получил статус "хорошего", но был удалён в процессе модерации как якобы "не относящийся к ответу". С учётом того, что вопрос сырой я не исключаю того, что вопрос опять будет переписан/переформулирован, а предыдущие ответы будут удалены как неотносящиеся к делу. Считаю это крайне порочной практикой: у нас насколько я знаю не принято менять вопросы до степени, когда предыдущие ранние ответы обесцениваются)

Итого! Коллеги, я озвучу своё мнение по отзывам. Вы хотите знать, какие отзывы не стоит публиковать на сайте, а увидев удалять? Объясняю по пунктам:

#### 1. На мете не стоит публиковать отзывы содержащие оскорбления и нецензурную лексику.

У нас уже есть правила дружелюбного поведения, которые являются достаточным основанием для исправления любого текста (вырезать мат, вырезать оскорбления -- а всё остальное оставить). Предпочтительно, чтобы сам участник оставивший подобный текст сделал корректировку, также её могут либо сделать принудительно (вырезав оскобления -- есть много участников имеющих права на инструменты модерирования), либо текст может быть удалён целиком (в ситуации когда кроме оскорблений/мата ничего нет). Также 
мы имеем прецеденты, когда авторы текстов настаивали на сохранении исходного текста по ряду причин (как-то, но не исчерпываясь: а) сохранение авторского стиля б) сохранение целостности произведения)

Отдельно хочу высказать мнение: для того, чтобы удалять оскорбления и нецензурщину не нужно вводить никаких дополнительных терминов типа "отзыв" (это одна из причин, по которой я продолжаю давать ответ в отсутствие чёткого определения термина "отзыв"). Неважно, что это за текст -- отзыв или не отзыв, содержит оскорбления или мат -- этому не место на мете или основном сайте. Мы -- за дружелюбное поведение!!

В русском языке достаточно способов выразить свою мысль без оскорбления, агрессии, перехода на личности. Я не буду [пересказывать](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8653/213987) [CoC](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/conduct), я просто [повторю своё мнение](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8654/213987), что невозможно дать общую формулировку, что является пассивной агрессией, переходом на личности, оскорблением. Увы, мы до сих пор не можем даже определиться является ли т.н. N-слово оскорбительным или нет -- и многочисленные споры, которые постоянно вспыхивают по этому поводу являются лучшим доказательством.

#### 2. Каждое подобное удаление должно иметь право на оспаривание решения

Я считаю, что каждый конкретный пример должен быть тщательным образом рассмотрен коллегиально (лично меня вполне устраивает если это будет делать не один конкретный человек, но будет решено коллегиально модсоставом. Вероятно, даже может высказываться не каждый из модераторов, просто по умолчанию я буду считать, что решение принимается всеми - то есть имеет место коллегиальная ответственность).

Я считаю, что каждый пример, когда участник не согласен с решением модераторов имеет право быть обсуждённым публично, а не через форму обратной связи с организацией.
Как участник я хочу прозрачности. В прошлом году были прецеденты, когда конфликты предлагалось обсуждать через форму обратной связи, после чего у ряда участников сложилось мнение, что невозможно узнать, что вообще произошло. Администрация настаивает на том, что нельзя раскрывать подробности рассмотрения подобных вопросов (доходя до абсурдных ситуаций, когда сам участник не против подобного раскрытия информации), но в итоге сама собственными руками подогревает настроения "от нас скрывают" и "с нами поступают несправедливо". Открытость и прозрачность -- вещь, которая автоматически помогает наладить этот процесс и снизить остроту негатива.

#### 3. Считаю мету сообщества местом, где разрешено размещать не только "отзывы", чтобы не понималось под этим термином.

Это крайне важный момент, имеющий самое непосредственное отношение к заданному вопросу. Цитирую: "Какие, на ваш взгляд, отзывы уместны на сайте, а какие лучше не публиковать, а увидев удалять?" Если мы соглашаемся с тем, что на мете допустимы не только отзывы, всё окей, у нас с вами совпадает мнение, если нет -- я проговорю вслух:

Если мы говорим о том, что если не отзыв - то сразу удаляем — то мы просто обязаны вернуться к вопросам "что есть мета" и поставить НОВЫЙ очень широкий вопрос "что можно постить на мете, а что нельзя". Просто вдумайтесь в этот вопрос и поймите, что раньше такого обсуждения вообще не было.

Я не хочу оказаться в ситуации, когда мы получили в руки инструмент для удаления любого вопроса, ответа, комментария на мете с нечёткими формулировками и прочим. Я не хочу сказываться в ситуацию, когда у нас начнётся шквал удалений старого и нового контента и произойдёт это после мимоходом введённого термина.

Мета — сайт с давними многолетними традициями, если нужно решительно изменить курс, то делать это нужно взвешенно, после вдумчивого и рассудительного обсуждения.

Итого, мета — не только для отзывов. (Для чего — давайте вне этой темы, я и так достаточно длинный ответ написал)

#### 4. Мета является идеальным местом для отзывов критического толка

Конечно же, приятно слушать только хвалебные отзывы, но критические отзывы являются наиболее полезными, так как указывают на недостатки и дают возможность увидев их исправить.

В самом критическом комментарии нет ничего плохого! Если вы думаете иначе попробую разубедить вас приведя такой пример:

Муж говорит жене "вот тут сделано неправильно". С его точки зрения это конструктивно и это правильно. Что слышит жена? "Ты год не говорил мне, что любишь меня и только и говоришь, что я делаю неправильно".

Мы как участники привыкли обращать внимание на факты, весь сайт приучает к технической парадигме — упор на знания, на факты, эмоции не приветствуются, мнения ненадёжны и т.п. Неужели кто-то правда думает, что когда раз в год мы мельком упоминаем, что so — это вообще-то одно из самых офигенных мест и поэтому мы сидим тут безвылазно — это какое-то вранье и лицемерие, а так-то если собрать все наши комментарии, где то тут по мелочи видим проблему, то там — то получается, что мы на 99,99% наших фраз только и делаем что критикуем?

Также я считаю, что возможность оставлять критические отзывы *публично*, а не через форму обратной связи администрации -- это отличнейшая возможность эти самые отзывы улучшить! Как говорится: одна голова хорошо - а две лучше!

Именно возможность коллективного творчества, когда многие участники вкладывают свою лепту в создание контента является огромным плюсом для администрации сайта, когда отзывы улучшаются, дополняются и становятся более ценными. Именно поэтому администрация должна быть заинтересована в построении саморегулирующегося сообщества, которое само найдёт огрехи в контенте и исправит их. (Далее читаем [текст из удалённого ответа](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8654/213987) -- почему администрация заинтересована в построении сообщества на мете и о том, какие проблемы, когда у нас участники не помнят контекст обсуждаемого вопроса)

Критика — очень полезна! Высказывайте критику, соблюдая правила дружелюбного поведения — и это принесёт пользу всему сайту! Критика допустима на сайте, это очевидно и подчёркивается на всех уровнях. Единственным требованием к критике является соблюдение правил дружелюбного поведения и это всё!

Если кто-то считает, что вашу критику необходимо удалить, потому что это уже говорилось вами ранее и говорилось не один и не два раза -- то можете спокойно повторить ещё и ещё, в этом нет никакого криминала:

*Важно. Если участник видит какую-то проблему и считает её крайне важной, то он может пытаться доносить до других участников и администрации эту проблему многократно.*

Приведу примеры из того, чем сам стал свидетелем. Когда ещё никто не видел проблемы с сайтом qaru -- я многократно подымал эту тему в разговорах с администрацией и пытался указать на то, что проблема крайне серьёзная и важная. Какое-то время от меня отмахивались, приводили аргументы. Через некоторое время стало понятно, что проблема большая и масштабная, сейчас администрация подхватила эту повестку, спрашивает советы ну  и в том числе предлагает какие-то свои варианты, что с этим делать.

Другая тема, про которую я постоянно напоминаю -- это то, что движок so уже много лет не могут допилить под SEO, чтобы не терять огромное количество трафика на том, что контент so стоит ниже в поисковой выдаче чем аналоги с похожим контектом или даже (что просто немыслимо!) сайты предлагающие автоперевод точно того же контента!

Вот и сейчас нашёл удобный повод напомнить, потому что я не хочу быть навязчивым и упоминать в любой неподходящей теме по любому поводу. Это наверное можно расценить как слишком навязчивое продавливание темы и часто использовалось как повод забанить участников с формулировкой "давление на сотрудников администрации". Поэтому я готов сформулировать ещё два пункта:

#### 5. Не стоит слишком часто повторять одни и те же критические отзывы, соблюдайте меру и не давите слишком сильно на сотрудников администрации

Полагаю, что тут уместно будет повторять одну и ту же критическую тему не чаще, чем раз в квартал. Исключений я вижу два, возможно их больше и стоит обсудить:

- сотрудник администрации сам просит вас напомнить о статусе через определённое время (сейчас занят другими вопросами, требуется получить информацию от другого сотрудника, отпуска и т.п.)
- сотрудник администрации сообщает вам, что вы слишком часто напоминаете об одной и той же теме и устанавливает чёткий срок "повторы ранее полугода этой темы будут расцениваться как навязчивые" (и наверное полгода - это максимальный срок, который стоит указывать в подобных предупреждениях, чтобы действительно важные темы не забывались)

#### 6. Не стоит упоминать одни и те же критические отзывы в несвязанных темах.

У нас на сайте принято обсуждать в одном топике одну проблему. Даже если вы считаете какую-то тему чрезвычайно важной для общественного обсуждения либо для напоминания администрации о том, что проблема до сих пор не решена — это не является индульгенцией и не даёт вам права упоминать эту тему при обсуждении *несвязанных* тем. Это может быть расценено участниками как продавливание, навязчивое поведение и т.п. Не уподобляйтесь спамерам, этого никто не любит.

Помимо этого у меня вот на примере именно поднятой темы и моего удалённого ответа как якобы нетематического появилось ещё два пункта:

#### 7. Критические отзывы не следует удалять в случае если автор злоупотребляет  изменением вопроса более одного раза, постоянно обесценивая ранее данные ответы или вынуждая авторов ответов вносить постоянные коррективы или добиваться удаления ответов

Подобная тема уже подымалась на мете - см. [Обновление вопроса по мере появления ответов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8565/213987), однако в связи со сложностью пока оставлена без ответа. В принципе, у нас уже есть сложившиеся традиции и правила, когда мы уже говорили о недопустимости подобных действий. Однако с учётом того, что модсостав крайне избирательно подошёл в данном случае к ситуации считаю необходимым дать отдельное пояснение.

На этом вроде бы пока всё. Кажется, удалось достаточно полно но кратко сформулировать первое приближение к ответу на вопрос "Какие, на ваш взгляд, отзывы уместны на сайте, а какие лучше не публиковать, а увидев удалять?" (при всём несовершенстве этого вопроса и неточности терминов)

Ан нет, вот ещё один вопрос я не заметил:

> И, что самое главное, почему вы так считаете?

Чтобы избежать поводов для упрёков, что мой ответ нетематичен и потому обязан быть удалён модераторами вынужден высказаться и по этому вопросу, тем более что он заявлен как самый главный.

Отвечаю. Я пристально следил за развитием ситуацию в так называемом "прошлом" году, полном конфликтов администрации и наиболее активными участниками, пытался в меру своих возможностей помочь разрешить эти конфликты.

Как мне кажется, в процессе мне удалось в достаточно мере понять мотивацию как обеих сторон и вынести полезные знания о том, каким мог бы быть компромисс в данных вопросах для обеих сторон.

Также, я достаточно хорошо [разбираюсь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election/2#post-728718) в прикладной психологии, чему посвятил более шести лет жизни, а также в вопросах построения сообществ.

Если моя помощь понадобится в решении подобных вопросов -- SoReadyToHelp.

Comment: Спасибо за текст. Вы начинаете с выделения слов из вопроса цитатами, а потом в цитатах уже ваши слова, потом обратно. Я, как читатель, сначала понял как–будто все цитаты из вопроса. Это вводит в заблуждение. Был бы очень благодарен, если бы вы поправили. На данный момент это выглядит аналогично [**вашему** запрету сарказма](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7593/6).

Comment: Stack Overflow, как социально, так и технически, разрабатывается на основе отзывов участников. Суть отзывов — улучшить предлагаемое решение еще на стадии разработки. Мета — этот тот же сайт вопросов и ответов, который дает возможность накапливать знания о самом движке и сообществе. Проблема появляется тогда, когда на просьбу отзыва по конкретному прикладному вопросу ответ участника содержит его личный манифест, относящийся к вопрос постольку—поскольку. И если он оказывается не реализован, появляются оскорбления вида «да им плевать на мнение участников», «они решают все, наше мнение ничто».

Comment: Было бы очень здорово избежать описанного выше.

Comment: "Если вы видите этот мой текст удалённым — то имейте ввиду, это уже вторая редакция этого сырого вопроса, которая привела мой текст к удалению" - ваш ответ был удален до правки вопроса, так что этот абзац немного не соответствует действительности.

Comment: "Я считаю, что каждый пример, когда участник не согласен с решением модераторов имеет право быть обсуждённым публично, а не через форму обратной связи с организацией" - с этим есть две проблемы. Первая - невозможность раскрытия персональных данных модераторами + неполнота доступа к этим данным у модераторов. В случае учёток-клонов модераторы видят очень общий summary по действиям, но не видят конкретных действий. Этого достаточно для принятия решения (если модератор долго работал с системой, и знает, на что обращать внимание), но совсем не достаточно для убеждения не-модераторов на мете.

Comment: ...хотя бы потому, что модератор представляет, что еще он может проверить в качестве подтверждения, и может проверить это сам. а обычный участник - не может и не представляет.

Comment: Вторая проблема - почти гарантированное отсутствие 100% доказательств умышленности нарушения. При вынесении решения всегда есть доля "по моему мнению", пусть даже очень небольшая. Даже если модератор уверен, что нарушение было, и было умышленным - он не может даже заявить об этом, и тем более не сможет попытаться объяснить свою точку зрения. Участник в ответ заявит, что модератор злостно клевещет, обратится в администрацию и потребует немедленно снять модератора с должности. Прецедент уже был, не хотелось бы еще раз наступать на те же грабли.

Comment: Какая именно особенность движка, по вашему, отрицательно влияет на SEO и требует допиливания?

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight это у Николаса нужно спрашивать. Он неоднократно про это говорил в прошлом.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky "Если вы не можете доверять суждению сообщества" почему вы тогда не доверяете сообществу и переоткрываете вопросы, закрытые сообществом?

Comment: Ну, я понял: любой т.н. "отзыв" можно назвать т.н. "манифестом" -- и это ещё одна прекрасная причина с невнятной формулировкой для выпиливания неугодных постов. Пост тематичен - [я аргументированно ответил на все вопросы и после этого спросил в какой точке мы находимся, вы ничего не смогли сказать](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/48792427#48792427). Даже модератор [согласился](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/48850067#48850067), что пост тематичен и удалён лишь во имя сохранения общественного спокойствия. "Отзывы можно, манифесты нельзя" - и их удалять, так?

Answer (score 4):

1. Удалять сообщения, нарушающие [правила](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice). TL;DR: оскорбляющие других пользователей и т.п.
2. Чтобы говорить про пассивную агрессию, нужно в вопросе написать определение этого термина. В прошлых обсуждениях к единому мнению по определению этого термина не пришли.
3. Критика не запрещена.
4. Мнение/критика компании - не клевета.

Comment: Ваш ответ совершенно не раскрывает проблему. Как вы «ваше мнение» отличите от «клеветы» со стороны? Кроме того, что если «ваше мнение», даже если вы так действительно думаете, не соотносится с действительностью или просто выдумка?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky просто на ваш вопрос невозможно ответить однозначно, пока вы термины не расшифруете. Ту же "пассивную агрессию".

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: Вы не поняли суть ответа. Она и состоит в том, что правила должны быть ровно такими, как в ответе.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: Например, мотивация для 4 пункта: иначе любую критику компании и её действий очень просто объявить клеветой. Если вы считаете это выражением недоверия к решением модсостава и компании, то да, мы не доверяем им.